# Cutting up a shapefile into smaller parts

Tags: shapefile, geometry, openstreetmap, linux

I've downloaded the 450MB [coastline shapefile](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/water-polygons) from OpenStreetMap, I want to split it up in smaller parts. Is there a way to generate a shapefile with only the polygons contained in a smaller area?

The file comes with the water areas already split up in rectangular shapes.

Comment: According to the docs, it's not "one big polygon," but has already been "divided into 100km x 100km squares."  Do you need to *clip* out smaller portions of those square features or would it suffice to *select* those squares covering your study region?

Comment: It would be enough if I could export a couple of those 100km squares. Not optimal, if I'm limited to such a big grid, but very doable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `ogr2ogr`, you can specify a bounding box that you'd like to clip by with `-clipsrc x_min y_min x_max y_max`, so for example, to only get the northern hemisphere of a global dataset you could do:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" borders_north.shp borders.shp -clipsrc -180 0 180 90
```

See the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) documentation for further options, including clipping to another geometry.

Comment: If you have an old GDAL version (<1.7) this "works": `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" borders_north.shp borders.shp -spat -180 0 180 90` It will not clip so if you have one big geometry you will still have to upgrade,

Comment: The file is of course in spherical mercator, so you will have to covnert the coordinates in someway.

Answer (score 4):

You can install and use qgis to load the file you downloaded; use the mouse or query the data for the features that you would like to select; and export the selected features to a new shapefile.

QGIS is a cross-platform (Linux, Windows, Mac) open source application with many common GIS features and functions.

A link containing tutorials that illustrates these steps in qgis is available here http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/